# How do I find where the Google Form is saved?

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

I've started a contract at a small company to update all their google forms. The forms were set up 5 years ago by the last contractor. Unfortunately this means none knows where the forms are saved on the google drive, or even the file name.

Is there a way to find where the form & scripts are saved with only the ID?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the form id use the following URL

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/<< add here the form id>>/edit
```

If you have access to form location the user interface will show a folder next to the form name. Click on it to open the form location.

If you don't have access to the form, a request access form should be shown. The form owner will receive an email. Additionally if the form was created using a Google Workspace account you ask the organization admin to transfer the ownership to an organization user in order to make them able to share the form with you.

Comment: Thanks Ruben

Unfortunately we're getting <i>Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.</i> 

Just to confirm I'm looking at the right thing, the form address I've got goes: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<<form id is here>>/viewform

Comment: @MTwem Nowadays the URL ending on `/viewform` doesn't include the form id. Please edit the question to be more specific about what you have... also include if the forms were created with the previous contractor account or with one of the client accounts, and if they have `@gmail.com`  accounts or Google Workspace accounts.